# t sql increment date column value based on previous row date value

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have columns of data  in table #Temp1 as follows: (there is an existing clustered Index on the table of Unit asc, dateTime asc)

```
rowID unit   dateTime          newUnit  dateDiff
  1    A    2018-06-01 04:10      1       0
  2    A    2018-06-01 04:12      0       2
  3    A    2018-06-01 04:15      0       3
  4    A    2018-06-01 04:15      0       0
  5    A    2018-06-01 04:16      0       1
  6    A    2018-06-01 04:17      0       1
  7    B    2018-06-22 23:12      1       -305
  8    B    2018-06-01 23:14      0       2
  9    B    2018-06-01 23:18      0       4
 10    B    2018-05-22 23:18      0       0
 11    B    2018-06-01 23:22      0       4
 12    B    2018-06-01 23:31      0       9
```

Ignoring the first row, when dateDiff is 0 I want to increase dateTime by 2 minutes on the previous row value. If the increased value of a new dateTime means it is now equal to or greater than the dateTime in the next row after that, it should increase the next datetime and keep doing so until the difference is greater than 0. The process should restart when there is a change of unit (newUnit = 1). dateDiff does not need to be updated with the new differences.

Next I want to update a another table #Temp2, that currently holds the old dateTime values, with the new dateTime values from #Temp1, based on rowID.

After some research on S.O. I figured something like the following might work, but I don't have the SQL knowledge to crack it!

```
  WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp1) > 0
        BEGIN
        UPDATE TOP (1) #Temp2  
        SET [dateTime] = DATEADD(minute, 2, #Temp1.[dateTime])
        FROM #Temp1
        WHERE #Temp2.moveID = #Temp1.moveID + 1  
           .... plus other conditions to update [dateTime]
    END
```

Any help on cracking this one is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions and an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by unit order by datetime) as seqnum,
             min(datetime) over (partition by unit) as min_datetime
      from #temp1 t
     )
update toupdate
    set datetime = dateadd(minute, 2 * seqnum - 2, min_datetime)
    where seqnum > 1;
```

This calculates a sequential number for each `unit`.  It then uses arithmetic to set the `datetime` value in each row.

Comment: Yes your solution works great thank you. I've also modified it to use the average of dateDiff over each partition rather than just an increment of 2.  To get better precision can you also help me out with casting the result of the dateDiff average calculation as a decimal to 1 decimal place?            The dateDiff values were calculated with  with:    CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,t1.dateTime, t2.dateTime)as decimal (10,2)) as dateDiff     but when dateDiff is used in the cte it seems to be overridden by the datatype assigned automatically by the cte??

Comment: @FyllSee . . . `DATEDIFF()` returns an integer.  Perhaps you should ask another question with sample data and desired results.